# Почему в консоли не выводится массив в первоначальном виде?

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Я хочу вывести массив в первоначальном виде 1 2 3 4 в первом console.log, но он в обоих местах вывода показывает 67 69 72 76 81, почему? А вот если вложенности в массиве нет, то все работает логично и первый консоль лог выводит 1 2 3 4 Почему??

```js
const a = [[1,2,3,4]];

console.log(a);

a[0].reduce((accum, e, i, ar)=>{
    ar[i]=accum+e
    return accum+e
}, 66);

console.log(a);
```

Comment: В первый раз выводит `[[1, 2, 3, 4]]`

Comment: здесь, когда нажмешь выполнить код, то да, а вот в хроме, мозиле нет(

Comment: А вы выводите так: `JSON.stringify(a)`. В косноли отображение идёт в конце, потому вы видите последний результат

Comment: специфика `log` и работы дебаг консоли браузера. попробуйте либо `console.dir` либо сериализацию в `json`. Дебаг консоль раскрывает там вложенность на момент клика, а не вызова кода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Объяснение в комментариях:

```js
const a = [[1,2,3,4]];

console.log(JSON.stringify(a)); // [[1, 2, 3, 4]]

a[0].reduce((accum, e, i, ar)=>{
    console.log(ar === a[0]); // true
    
    ar[i] = accum + e; // массив передаётся по ссылке,
    //потому изменения `ar` - это изменения `a[0]`
    
    return accum + e;
}, 66);

console.log(JSON.stringify(a)); // [[67, 69, 72, 76]]
```

Comment: я скопировал код в консоль он все равно вывел в хроме 67, 69, 72, 76, может я не понял что имели в виду, скриншот добавил к вопросу

Comment: @consoleлох Обновил ответ. Я же сказал, для вывода в консоли браузера используйте `JSON.stringify`

Comment: да, просто не прочитал ответ, стало яснее

Comment: @consoleлох Если ответ вам помог, то не забудьте пожалуйста отметить его как принятый (поставить зелёную галочку слева от ответа) :)

Comment: разобрался, спасибо